# Traduction Function like Trad(String Language, String Word)

Tags: java, split

I'm writing a function that when you click on "FR" button it will translate all the text of the jlabel in French and when you click on "En" in English.

**input .txt**

```
Bon de Commande;Order Form  
S'identifier;Login  
Entrez votre identifiant;Enter Username  
Entrez votre mot de passe;Enter Password  
Connexion;Connection  
Bienvenue;Welcome
```

**java**

```
public static String getTraduction(String language, String word) throws IOException {

    String delim = ";";
    String line = null;
    int size = getNbrLigne(PathLangue);
    String[][] info = new String[size][0];  //String[FR][EN][NL]
    String[] temp; 
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(PathLangue));

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        temp = line.split(delim);
        System.out.println("temp : " + line);
        info[b][a] = temp[a];       //info[0][0] -> FR
        info[b][a] = temp[a+1];     //info[0][1] -> EN
        //info[b][a] = temp[a+2];       // info[0][2] -> NL

        System.out.println("FR : "+temp[a]+" EN : "+temp[a+1]);

        if (temp[a].equals(word) == true){
            if (language.equals("FR")) {
                (info[b][a]) = temp[a];
                break;
            }
            if (language.equals("EN")) {
                (info[b][a+1]) = temp[a+1];
                break;
            }
            /*if (langue.equals("NL")) {
                (info[b][a+2]) = temp[a+2];
                break;
            }*/

            }

            b++;
        }       
    scanner.close();
    return info[b][a];
}
```

The problem with this code is when I do the split, I got :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

The first sysout works but not the second one because the error is generate just when I do the split :/

In my final version I want to integrate FR, EN, NL( Nederlands), DE (Dutch) and PL (Polish).

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Note: in English, "traduction" is "translation" ;) Encore un faux ami...

Comment: `DE` is for german, Dutch is the Language of the Nederlands.

Comment: Also, look at this library, it can help you instead of writing the same thing again and again: https://github.com/fge/msg-simple

Comment: :p du moment que les gens d'ici comprennent c'est l'essentiel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line :

```
String[][] info = new String[size][0]
```

The second dimension is empty so when you access `info[b][a]` you will get the exception since the 2nd dimension will always be out of bounds.

What you need to do is initialize the array with the required size for the 2nd dimension as well for example :

```
String[][] info = new String[size][2]; // As in your case you access indicies 0 and 1 in the 2nd dimension
```